# Repeated GPS coordinates in data are creating stacked points on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, excel

I have 30+ events of data collection for each GPS location (previous person on project has simply added new rows for each data collection period). When I import the excel file (via CSV format), each location therefore has 30+ gps points stacked on top of one another. 
How can I get a single GPS point to reference 30+ entries without also having 30+ repeated spots on the map?

[image]

Comment: I would fix this in excel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel. It gets a bit more complicated trying to get the unique over 3 columns but it's just an extension of the formula in that answer.

Comment: Still not quite what I am looking for. I need to hang on to the associated data for each repeated location (each entry is a separate event).

Comment: Almost all GIS data is one shape to one record, if you want 30 point records you need 30 points... that's just the way it is. You can *relate* your data such that one geometry references multiple rows in an aspatial table like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137711/how-do-i-join-multiple-features-with-a-single-geometry-less-table-entry that way you 'see' only one point but can query all the related rows.